# How can I create a function in SQL with 2 parameters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I'm trying to create a function that SUMs the total number of minutes of actual duration for videos with a Finished status given a UserID as a parameter. This is what I have so far but I can't figure out how to add the parameter for the Finished status. This comes from a different table of Status that has a StatusID and StatusText. Or would I do a NOT NULL statement?

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.vc_VideoRunTime(@userID int)
RETURNS int AS 
BEGIN 
DECLARE @returnValue int
SELECT @returnValue = DATEDIFF (n, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) FROM vc_Video
WHERE vc_Video.vc_UserID = @userID
RETURN @returnValue
END
GO
```

Comment: Yes I am using SQL Server

Comment: So what is missing in the above, another input parameter?  Or, do you want to return more than one value?

Comment: I only need to return the total minutes but some videos aren't finished yet so the results are NULL and I'm trying to remove the NULL results. I'm just not sure how to add input parameter for the finished status to only get return values with total minutes

Comment: you wanted the function to return `total number of minutes` and also `finished status` ?

Comment: I only want to return the total number of minutes but only return videos that have a finished status. And not return any video that has "NULL" results for the total minutes since some videos are not completed and don't have the total minutes yet

Comment: why then not just modify your WHERE clause like so `WHERE vc_Video.vc_UserID = @userID AND vc_Video.EndDateTime IS NOT NULL` clause?

Comment: How about adding 'AND EndDateTime IS NOT NULL' in your WHERE clause? Also from what I understood it looks like you might need a GROUP BY vcUserID to get the total minutes

Comment: Thank you Carlo Bos! That was exactly what I was trying to do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your finished status is represented as a `NULL` endtime, then your function is fine:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.vc_VideoRunTime (
    @userID int
)
RETURNS int AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @returnValue int;
    SELECT @returnValue = SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, v.StartDateTime, v.EndDateTime))
    FROM vc_Video v 
    WHERE v.vc_UserID = @userID ;

    RETURN @returnValue;
END;
GO
```

Why?  The `DATEDIFF()` will return `NULL` if either argument is `NULL`.  The `SUM()` will then return `NULL`.

Note that I changed the `n` to `minute`.  This is much more readable. (I don't know anyone who uses the "n" option for "minute", it makes me think "nanosecond".)

If you actually want the function to return `0` in this case, then use `COALESCE()`:

```
    RETURN COALESCE(@returnValue, 0);
```